# How do I send telnet erase line (EL) with Java Apache commons?

Tags: java, telnet, apache-commons-net

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now:

I've set up an apache commons telnet client that can send commands to a server and read responses. My program basically works like this:

```
    TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();

    // Add option handlers
    TerminalTypeOptionHandler ttopt = new TerminalTypeOptionHandler(
            "VT100", false, false, true, false);
    EchoOptionHandler echoopt = new EchoOptionHandler(true, false, true,
            false);
    SuppressGAOptionHandler gaopt = new SuppressGAOptionHandler(true, true,
            true, true);
    try {
        telnetClient.addOptionHandler(ttopt);
        telnetClient.addOptionHandler(echoopt);
        telnetClient.addOptionHandler(gaopt);
    } catch (InvalidTelnetOptionException e) {
        System.err.println("Error registering option handlers: "
                + e.getMessage());
        throw new IOException();
    }

    // Connect to server
    telnetClient.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);

    byte[] data = new byte[] { 'f', 'o', 'o', '\r', '\n' };

    // Send "foo"
    telnetClient.getOutputStream().write(data);
    telnetClient.getOutputStream().flush();

    // ...

    // Erase previous input
    data = new byte[] { (byte) TelnetCommand.IAC, (byte) TelnetCommand.EL,
            '\r', '\n' };

    telnetClient.getOutputStream().write(data);
    telnetClient.getOutputStream().flush();
```

What i'm trying to do is to send a telnet EL command to erase the entire line of previously sent characters ("foo"). Telnet commands are always sent with a preceding IAC character and that's what i'm sending too.

I have a working implementation of a listener which reads the servers echoes and prints them out.

The problem is that when i send the IAC-EL, the characters are not interpreted as a command. The IAC-EL characters are instead echoed back appended to the previous input as "foo�ø".

Could this be some problem with the line mode set to one character at a time?

Also the server side is runnning VT100 through the telnet. Maybe there is some way to send a VT100 escape sequence to erase the line instead, e.g. "←[1K". I've been unsuccessful with sending a VT100 sequence soo far anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you sniffed what is actually sent? I would expect the Apache code to escape the IAC, so you are really sending IAC-IAC-EL.

You should be calling TelnetClient.sendCommand(EL).

Comment: I did a sniff on the packets sent and you're right, it actually escapes the IAC character so IAC-IAC-EL is sent. However if i try to send only an EL the sniffer shows that it only sends the EL by itself (no IAC). How do i manage to send only one IAC followed by an EL character?

Comment: @snipes83 didn't I just answer that?

Comment: I method for sending commands would've been great but i can't find one. The TelnetClient class only has "sendAYT()" for sending "are you there" commands. I had a look at the source for the sendAYT-method and it seems to write this byte array to the output stream:

    static final byte[] _COMMAND_AYT = { (byte) TelnetCommand.IAC, (byte) TelnetCommand.AYT };

Why isn't the IAC escaped? Special handling i guess.

Comment: I can't find the method you're refering to.

I'm using commons-net v2.2

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html#sendCommand(byte). Your version is out of date. Upgrade.

Comment: I upgraded to commons-net 3.0.1 and used the new method "sendCommand()" and it worked! Problem solved. Thank you EJP!